# Remove a custom MKOverlayView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I'm using a subclassed `MKOverlay` and subclassed `MKOverlayView` to display WMS tiles. Got it running well.

I'm running into the issue of removing the `MKOverlayView` when I'm done displaying the tiles. I can remove the `MKOverlay` just fine:

```
-(void)removeWMSOverlay {    
    for (WMSOverlay *overlay in self.mapView.overlays) {
        if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[WMSOverlay class]]) {            
            MKOverlayView *test = [self.mapView viewForOverlay:overlay];

            [self.mapView removeOverlay:overlay];
        }
    }
}
```

But the `WMSOverlayView` is still there and still running its code (constantly checking if new tiles can be draw) which creates some lag.

I don't know where to find a list of `MKOverlayViews` that are active. I tried:

```
-(void)removeWMSOverlay {    
    for (WMSOverlay *overlay in self.mapView.overlays) {
        if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[WMSOverlay class]]) {            
            MKOverlayView *test = [self.mapView viewForOverlay:overlay];

            [self.mapView removeOverlay:overlay];

            [test removeFromSuperview];

            test = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

to no effect. The code is still running.

Even tried to keep a reference of it around to nil:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[WMSOverlay class]]) {

        WMSOverlayView *view = [[WMSOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        view.alpha = .8;

        self.wmsOverlayView = view;

        return view;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

-(void)removeScene {    
    for (WMSOverlay *overlay in self.mapView.overlays) {
        if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[WMSOverlay class]]) {            
            [self.mapView removeOverlay:overlay];

            self.wmsOverlayView = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Can I remove the `MKOverlayView` or do I need to figure out how to reuse the view?

EDIT:

I tried reusing the `MKOverlayView`:

```
else if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[WMSOverlay class]]) {
    self.wmsOverlayView = [[WMSOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];

    return self.wmsOverlayView;
}
```

and added a timer to show that more then one MKOverLayView is runing:

```
-(void)amIStillHere {
    DLog("I'M STILL RUNNING | self: %@", self);
}
```

They don't get reused or go away:

```
 DEBUG | -[WMSOverlayView startTimer] | I'M STILL RUNNING | self: <WMSOverlayView: 0x1d84afe0; frame = (6.02801e+07 9.44092e+07; 2.30324e+06 2.10344e+06); opaque = NO; layer = <MKOverlayClusterProxyLayer: 0x21bf3ff0>>
 DEBUG | -[WMSOverlayView startTimer] | I'M STILL RUNNING | self: <WMSOverlayView: 0x21be1a80; frame = (6.06487e+07 9.2838e+07; 2.36776e+06 2.15038e+06); opaque = NO; layer = <MKOverlayClusterProxyLayer: 0x1d8e2a20>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curious, I added the NSCacheDelegate to see when an item is evicted (I was concerned about having a NSCache for each `WMSOverlayView` and how they would behave and memory usage, I set the cache to 32mb and don't want to gobble up all memory). I tried naming each cache so I could see if there were two caches, I could see if the old cache was cleared out to make room in the memory for the newer cache. Realized each cache was always named the same:

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if (self.wmsOverlayView == nil) {
        self.wmsOverlayView = [[WMSOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay withCacheName:@"CACHE!"];
    }
    else {
        self.wmsOverlayView = [[WMSOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay withCacheName:@"THE NEW BETTER CACHE!"];
    }

    return self.wmsOverlayView;
}
```

I also noticed that `self.wmsOverlayView` was always `nil` and always naming the cache CACHE!. So the `wmsOverlayView` does get removed when the overlay is removed. But my timer kept going off. So I refactored my code to remove the timer and when I removed the `WMSOverlay`, the cache was cleared out (got my `cache:willEvictObject:` NSLog spammed).

So I believe the timer was keeping the `WMSOverlayView` alive.

Moral of the story: don't place a timer in a `MKOverlayView`.